# Rails 4 ActiveMailer: email loses attachments

Tags: ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4, email-attachments

This is in a Rails 4 app. I'm trying to send emails with attachments for the first time. It's a really basic test email:

```
class Emailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def test_attachments
    attachments['file.pdf'] = File.read('/path/to/file.pdf')
    mail(to: me@me.com, from: sender@me.com, body: "")
  end    
end

Emailer.test_attachments.deliver
```

This results in an error. *IndexError string not matched* Looking at the API docks, it looks like attachments is an instance method, so my next try uses that:

```
class Emailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def test_attachments
    mail(to: me@me.com, from: sender@me.com, body: "")
    mail.attachments['file.pdf'] = File.read('/path/to/file.pdf')
  end    
end

Emailer.test_attachments.deliver
```

This results in the attachment contents sent in the body of the email. Here's the mail instance:

```
#<Mail::Message:70259446276180, Multipart: false, Headers: <Date: Tue, 08 Jul 2014 12:09:14 -0400>, <From: sender@me.com>, <To: ["me@me.com"]>, <Message-ID: <53bc17c1e3194_122583fe68982dbc473cc@Johns-iMac-3.local.mail>>, <Subject: >, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: text/html>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit>>
```